# What could be a unit test case for the s3/sqs event when unmarshalling json to struck in Go Lang?

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

What could be a unit test case for the s3/sqs event when unmarshalling json to struck in Go?

One option that comes to mind is if the "Body" is empty, but not sure what else could it be.

Code example:

```
type Event struct {
    Message string `json:"Message"`
}

func unmarshal(message events.SQSMessage) (s3Event, error) {

        var e Event
        err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(message.Body), &e)
        if err != nil {
            return s3Event, err
        }

        var s3Event events.S3Event
        err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(e.Message), &sqsEvent)
        if err != nil {
            return s3Event, err
        }
        return s3Event, nil

}
```

Would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Premise: I'm not sure if I've fully understood your question. Furthermore, the code has some issues that cause me hard-time to figure out what's going on. With that being said, I'll try to help you by providing a piece of working software (it's not very useful) together with a piece of software written just to test it. Maybe, this can help you in figuring out your issue.

##### `unmarshal.go` file

```golang
package unmarshaltest

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
)

type Event struct {
    Message string `json:"body"`
}

func Unmarshal(message events.SQSMessage) (string, error) {
    rawBytes, _ := json.Marshal(message)
    var e Event
    json.Unmarshal(rawBytes, &e)
    if e.Message == "" {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("err while unmarshaling")
    }
    return e.Message, nil
}
```

One thing I fixed and you should pay attention to is how you name your functions. If you call your function `unmarshal` with lowercase `u` it means that this function should not be exported from this package (it's private). So I changed the name with the `U` as I supposed you wanna test this function.

##### `unmarshal_test.go` file

```golang
package unmarshaltest

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "testing"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestUnmarshal(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("Unmarshal_NotEmpty_Message", func(t *testing.T) {
        var sqsMsg events.SQSMessage
        sqsEventRaw := `{ "messageId": "19dd0b57-b21e-4ac1-bd88-01bbb068cb78", "receiptHandle": "MessageReceiptHandle", "body": "My own event payload!", "attributes": { "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1", "SentTimestamp": "1523232000000", "SenderId": "123456789012", "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1523232000001" }, "messageAttributes": {}, "md5OfBody": "4d1d0024b51659ad8c3725f9ba7e2471", "eventSource": "aws:sqs", "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123456789012:MyQueue", "awsRegion": "us-east-1" }`
        json.Unmarshal([]byte(sqsEventRaw), &sqsMsg)
        res, err := Unmarshal(sqsMsg)
        assert.Equal(t, "My own event payload!", res)
        assert.Nil(t, err)
    })

    t.Run("Unmarshal_Empty_Message", func(t *testing.T) {
        res, err := Unmarshal(events.SQSMessage{})
        assert.Equal(t, "", res)
        assert.NotNil(t, err)
    })
}
```

Here you can find a simple piece of code that is used to test the two possible execution flows that our code might take.
You should also pay attention to how you write the code. It's very hard to swap the invocation to the `json.Unmarshal` function with a mock as it's hard-coded into the code. If your wish is to be able to mock out this function, you should rely on interfaces in your production code and replace them with mocks during tests.
Let me know if this clarifies something and if you need something else!